# Why is my code throwing the error "prototype does not exist"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have string coming in the request that can have multiple words that i need to check in the array list if any of comma separated value in the string is 
in the array list return true. My code below is throwing an error:

> prototype does not exist

main.ts

```
const ContentList = ["check", "string", "in", "the", "array"]

private ValidateRequestArgs(str) {
        let arr = new Array();
        arr = ContentList;

        arr.prototype.contains = function(str) {
            return this.indexOf(str) > -1;
        };
    }


this.validateRequestArgs("check,string");
```

Comment: Why are you trying to add the `contains` method to the prototype at all?

Comment: @hussain I don't have the input to give a complete answer but for your title when you `new` an object it doesnt have a prototype property. The prototype exists as part of a type that can be newed. So `Array` has a prototype. `new Array()` has the methods that the prototype have but not the `prototype` property verbatim

Comment: You're using `const` and `let`, so there is no need for any of this. Just use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) with `.every()`, literally what it's for. On the general programming side, if you're assigning `arr`, just say `let arr = ContentList`, don't first assign it something and then immediately throw that away. Also, since `new Array()` is a can of worms, the general way to create a new array is using the JS literal syntax, `let arr = [];`

Answer (score 0):

The problem you want to solve requires the function below. But I am not sure this what you wanted because it has nothing to do with the function you wrote.

```
private ValidateRequestArgs(str) {
     return ContentList.some(w => str.indexOf(',' + w + ',') > -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the actual answer is "because `arr` is an instance, not the object definition", the actual take-away message here is more important, so keep reading.

JavaScript is a prototype inheritance language, meaning that anything with a prototype can be instanced using `new`, and those instances all get a reference to the single, definitive, prototype. Many instances, but only one prototype. Accessing the prototype associated with the actual object function requires using `.prototype`, accessing it through a specific instance requires using `__proto__`, but either accessor returns *the same* prototype. As such, one thing you can't do is "add something to an instance's prototype", because there is no "instance" prototype, you'll be modifying the universal prototype for that type of object. However you get your reference to it: modifying it, modifies it. So everything else is still tied to the same prototype. That you just modified. For everything.

What it *looks* like you want, is for `arr` to have a function `.contains()`, so if that's the case, just literally do that:

```
arr.contains = function(...) { ...}
```

`arr` is still a JavaScript object at its core, you can tack on as many properties on the fly as you need.

But then we get to: **but don't do that**, because standard JS already lets you write code that does what you want as one liner. There is literally no reason to write a function and then tack it onto the object instance(s) you're working with.

You're clearly using modern JS, so assuming performance isn't an issue, you can use the standard JS array functions already have available to you:

```
const ContentList = ["check", "string", "in", "the", "array"]

// let's check some content
let inputFromSomewhere = "check,string,where";
let arr = inputFromSomewhere.split(',');

// if there can be spaces around the commas, then you'll
// need to split on "comma possibly surrounded by spaces":
//
// let arr = inputFromSomewhere.split(/\s*,\s*/);

// check which terms are in the list
let yesno = arr.map(v => ContentList.indexOf(v)>-1);

  // yesno is now an array of true/false values

// check whether all terms are in the list:
let allPresent = list.reduce((a,v) => a && v);

  // allPresent is a single true/false value

// we can even do this in one step:
allPresent = arr.every(v => ContentList.indexOf(v)>-1);
```

And so on. The array prototype already has *tons* of functions to make all of this possible without having to write prototype-polluting things, so head over to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array, spend 10, 15 minutes reading through the list of functions that are on offer (because there will be a ton that you probably didn't know already existed) and up your programming game =)

Comment: i did not understand your answer i am expecting string to the validate function and what you have purposed is array based

Comment: If you can write `this.validateRequestArgs("check,string");` then you can also write `["check", "string"]`; I've added the split step explicitly for you, but I can recommend updating your post to explain why you have a string with commas (because who knows, maybe what you're actually doing means you can trivially get that delivered as array already, instead)

Comment: i have to convert to array string for the function specifically but `"check","string"` that would be coming from client request

Comment: Then you'll need a `string.split(',')` ("split on comma"), or `input.split(/\s*,\s*/)` ("split on comma, ignoring whitespace around it. remove that too").

Comment: You should be using const not let for all those variables apart from the last one, which you update.  const inputFromSomewhere = '...'; const arr = inputFromSomewhere.split(',') etc.

Comment: you are clearly unfamiliar with the performance hit of declaring a const. Unless you _need_ the protection of a `const` there is no reason to declare it as such. If you just need a variable, and in this case we do, then if you're in function scope, `let` and `var` work fine. If you _need_ block scope, `let` is your only option. Don't mistake rules from jslint or prettier for "what should be used". They enforce uniform style. That's all they do.

Comment: Clearly, you are not reading the same articles that I am, articles that state the opposite regarding performance of const because const allows engines to optimise.  That aside, we should be writing code that is readable to humans, and const communicates valuable information to both the reader and the engine. Leave the engine worry about optimising performance except in those rare cases where performance is critical. code first optimise later.  Using const isn't a style thing its a semantic thing.  linters enforce it not because it looks nice, but because its better to write code that way.

Comment: indeed we don't appear to: and so I'm goping to say that if you want const, by all means do, but unless something *is* a constant I will keep advocating not to call it one. Derivative arrays that are thrown away at the end of a function are constants only if you squint and look at them at a slight angle.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question, because you are trying to set the prototype on an instance of an array, which doesn't have a prototype, and not on the Array object which does.

Ignoring the other issues with the example, to give arrays a method contains(), do this in your init code...

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(str) {
  return this.indexOf(str) > -1;
}
```

Now, to do what I think you want to do (its not clear from the question), you need something like this

```
const contentList = ["check", "string", "in", "the", "array"];
function validateRequestArgs(args) {
  args = args.split(',');
  for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (!contentList.contains(args[i])) return false;  // word not in list
  }
  return true;
}
validateRequestArgs("check,string") // returns true
validateRequestArgs("not,this") // returns false
```

Comment: This might be an XY problem but you dont really answer their question at all.

Comment: Updated my answer to answer the question as asked.

Comment: Why would you write any of this code, when modern JS (which we're clearly using, given `const` and `let`) already comes with `.every()` and `.reduce()`?

Comment: It's not for me to question why the OP wants to not use the modern methods, just answering the question as asked.  Which if you look at the first comment on my answer I got a downvote for not doing that well enough (I then added the first paragraph).

So, what do I do?  I get a downvote if I don't answer the question literally and a downvote if I do.  Sucks to be me I guess.

As for my answer being pure JS well, it's just an example the contents of the function are what is important.

Comment: If he changes the question to something like "what is the correct way to do this in ES6? then that's a different ball game.

Comment: That is definitely not the case on Stackoverflow. When we write answers, it is our responsibility to also make sure we don't teach people to use anti-patterns, or to use 25 lines of custom, elaborate code when 1 line of standard library code already does what the code's intention was. Of course, make sure to answer the actual question (in this case, that's "why do I get this prototype error"), that's the most important part, but also make sure your answer explains why there is a better way to do this, and what that way is.